# Is there any way to validate a purchase against Google Play, not the cache, from within an app?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, google-play-developer-api

I have a one time purchase in my application. It enables all the features of the application.

When a user purchases the sku on their phone... everything works fine. We see the event returned by the billing client and record the purchase of the premium mode via setting a boolean in a local db. The local Google Play cache is updated properly.

Our problem is when they install on another device. Imagine wanting to use it on a tablet and your phone OR you lost your phone and got another.

We have been using the "query purchases" method of the billing client to validate a purchase. They install the app and I would assume that the purchase history would be added to the local cache at this time.

Generally, it works. But a non-negligible amount of users need to restart their phones several times or wait DAYS from Google to get their @#$% together and actually add the purchase history to their cache.

Their docs say that method only queries the local cache. https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient#querypurchases

The Google Play Developer API lets use query for purchases but we need the purchase token in order to validate anything. If Google Play can't return a purchase token since it has no record of a purchase...  what do we do?

How does everyone else deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`queryPurchases` relies on the cache on device. So if a user's device doesn't have cache updated in time, you will see this behavior. To solve it you should use [queryPurchaseHistoryAsync](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.html#queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(java.lang.String,%20com.android.billingclient.api.PurchaseHistoryResponseListener)) inside `queryPurchases` as follows

```
override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
        when (billingResult.responseCode) {
            BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK -> {
                ...
                queryPurchasesAsync()
            }
            ...
        }
    }

fun queryPurchasesAsync() {
        val purchasesResult = HashSet<Purchase>()
        var result = playStoreBillingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP)
        if(nullOrEmpty(result)){
            queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(...) // response is returned to onPurchaseHistoryResponse
        }else{
         ... // here you add your existing logic to give users access to products and services 
        }
    }
```

Aside: since you use the tag [google-play-developer-api](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/), does your app have a server? If so you could set the boolean on your server instead of using a local cache and grab the entitlement information from your server. The advantage of this approach is that when your app becomes cross-platform then it doesn't matter if the user made a purchase through Android or the web, they will get access to the premium content by checking with your server.

ref: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/master/TrivialDriveKotlin

Comment: This is a good partial solution but queryAsync only returns the latest of each sku. If they purchased several and refunded the last one I have no way to interpret the data.

It looks like the only way is by building middleware with access to the analytics api to query accurate purchase history and determine user entitlement.

Comment: 1) Strictly speaking we do not permit a user to buy more than one item per SKU. 2) queryPurchases will return all active purchases every time the user opens the app. 3) Before a user can repurchase a product, your app has to first consume it with `consumeAsync`, in which case such a purchase becomes forgotten/untracked by our systems. So in your case you should not call consumeAsync for one time purchases. 

If this explanation and the TrivialDriveKotlin sample still misses what you need, please elaborate on your use case.

Comment: Also try to run the snippet I provide to the linked post and see if purchase history addresses your concerns. I suspect it might in fact.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57529322/11798929

Comment: Querypurchasehistory returns all purchases for subscriptions even they arent active. How can it be used to understand if any subscription is active?

Comment: In android Billing 2.1.0, in the Java version, `result = playStoreBillingClient.queryPurchases(` gives a warning: *condition is always false* so the effect would be that queryPurchaseHistoryAsync() *never* triggers !